# how to get the inputstream to configuration file lying under web-inf folder in tomcat in java?

Tags: java, web-applications

i want to get the inputstream to configuration file  lying under webinf folder  in tomcat in java ?i want the configuration file as inputstream  lying under web-inf folder  in tomcat in java . I tried below code

```
InputStream xwikicfgis = FIPSSOAuthServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.cfg");
```

but its trying to search  the file under web-inf/classes folder but my file lies directly under web-inf folder. i am not getting how to point the path to web-inf instead of web-inf/classes folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it using servletConfig.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/filename") from any servlet.

Comment: if i need to get inputstream to any java class file lying uder web-inf/classes folder should i give complete path(i mean including package like com.myclass.Test) or simply name of file like Test. My another understanding is it will search first inside classes folder if not found then under lib folder right?

Comment: You should follow directory structure in your classes dir(just unpack your archive and look inside). N.B. Use "/" delimeter even in Windows(not backslash).

Comment: Thaks Artem. One last thing is this servlet config is available in servlet class. What if i need  to do it in some other java class which is not servlet

Comment: You can use some holder class which will be initialized by servlet at server startup with desired data. Then just use that holder from any class you need.

Answer (score 3):

use javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath(String)

the call

```
String webappBase = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

will point you to the doc base of your webapp, this is the parent of WEB-INF

after that you can use

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(webappBase + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + 
                                            File.separator + "config.cfg");
```

to get your input stream

Comment: getRealPath() is not workable if archive with application isn't unpacked after deployment(e.g. in case of using Weblogic AS).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") + "/webapps/your project name/foo.cfg
```

Tomcat can't work without CATALINA_HOME, so we can use it without any additional config file or something else and you don't need to take with you huge ServletContext.