# Groovy: File path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, groovy

Trying to read a Xml file from `webapps` folder. I am using eclipse as IDE.Code is `def dir = new File("webapps/WEB-INF/file.txt)`.
This works if I test this class from a `main()` but when I run it on Tomcat server it throws `FileNotFoundException` because it is trying find the file in `Eclipse Installation Directory/webapps/WEB-INF/file.txt`
Application is getting deployed at Tomcat installation directory.

**Updated Code**

```
def dir = this.class.getResource("webapps/WEB-INF/appEntryXslt/appEntryToSEGRequest")
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
 //do something with the file
}
```

But this also did not work. I want to read all the files from a directory.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710865/how-to-get-the-inputstream-to-configuration-file-lying-under-web-inf-folder-in-t?rq=1

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112936/how-do-i-reference-a-file-that-is-placed-in-the-web-inf-folder-when-using-arquil has another option (moving the file into WEB-INF/classes)

Comment: @tim_yates Added updated code. I am not sure how would I read each file from `ResourceStream`